# Problems installing R on Linux CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, r, centos

When installing R on Linux CentOS 6.2 I get the following:

```
Error: Package: R-core-2.10.0-2.el5.x86_64 (/R-core-2.10.0-2.el5.x86_64)
           Requires: libtk8.4.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-2.10.0-2.el5.x86_64 (/R-core-2.10.0-2.el5.x86_64)
           Requires: libtcl8.4.so()(64bit)
```

There are several helps out there for this type of error when using CentOS 4 or 5, but not for 6.2.  Has anyone found a solution with this OS version?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I'd honestly recommend installing [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL):

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and then just doing

```
yum install R
```

Answer (score 9):

The above did not work for me.  I had to install tcl.

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install tcl
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install R
```

Answer (score 7):

Now it is even easier:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install R
```