# Installing R-devel & R-core-devel on RHEL 6

Tags: r, centos, rhel6

Following the release of R 3, I was having several yum error messages relating to R when yum updating my system. After yum removing R and its dependencies I started again from scratch. However, I cannot get R-devel or R-core-devel installed and cannot get around this issue. Here are my error messages following `yum install R-core-devel R-devel`

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.1.0-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xz-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicu-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.1.0-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: R-java-devel = 3.1.0-5.el6 for package: R-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.1.0-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicu-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.1.0-5.el6 will be an update
---> Package xz-devel.x86_64 0:4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicu-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
R-java-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of R-core = ('0', '3.0.2', '1.el6')
R-java-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of R-core-devel = ('0', '3.0.2', '1.el6')
```

What does this mean and how can I resolve the issue

Comment: It tells you that it misses a dependency: `Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 (epel) Requires: libicu-devel`. Do you have that installed? If not you might want to install it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The following  answer worked for me:

[Problems installing R on Linux CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468164/problems-installing-r-on-linux-centos-6-2)

Specifically, I did this:

```
$ sudo yum install texinfo-tex
$ rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install tcl
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum install R
```