# error: zlib library and headers are required R on HPC

Tags: r, compilation, redhat, zlib, configure

System: 
`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)`

I’ve installed zlib 1.2.11 on the home folder of a Red Hat HPC as part of the process for installing R base 3.4.0.

I get this error even after successful install of zlib

`checking for inflateInit2_ in -lz... no
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required`

I’ve checked R documentation and configure file for the issue of R requiring versions newer than 1.2.6 but not lexicographically recognizing 1.2.11 as >1.2.6, and that particular bug was patched in R 3.4.

I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076936/zlib-bz2-library-and-headers-are-requried-for-compiling-r) posted previously and the response is not relevant due to R 3.4 resolving that issue.

Any suggestion and/or input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Installing R is a more suitable question for super user stack exchange. It would be pretty amazing if Red Hat does not have a repository with an up to date version of R as an RPM.

Comment: Perhaps try EPEL [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25855394/215487)?